# Need to store the post_id and user_id in read_statuses table using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When i initiate the show action the controller want to store the post_id and user_id into the another table.But it need to store for the first occurrence only For eg. (if user 1 opens the post 1 for the first time it creates an entry into the database but not at when he view the same post for the second time)
Post controller show cation will be:

```
def show
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
  @read_status= ReadStatus.create(user_id: current_user,post_id: @post.id)
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :read_statuses
  has_many :users,through: :read_statuses
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :read_statuses
  has_many :posts, through: :read_statuses
end
```

Read status model:

```
class ReadStatus < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I need to store the user_id and post_id in the read status table only when the user views the post for the first time only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an instance method `mark_read_by_user` to your model `Post` and inside it, use [first_or_create](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) to create the association record only if it doesn't exist.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  def mark_read_by_user(user)
    self.read_statuses.where(post_id: id, user_id: user.id).first_or_create
  end
end
```

In controller:

```
def show
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
  @read_status = @post.mark_read_by_user(current_user)
end
```

Comment: Got the answer but how it will get the current  post id in the record when passing as parameter . { self.read_statuses.first_or_create(post_id: id, user_id: user.id) }

Comment: I mistook and defined the methos in the controller

Comment: In `post_id: id`, `id` is the ID of current post, on which you called the method inside your controller action.

Comment: @PraveenR On calling method `mark_read_by_user` on `@post` object the `id` will be the id of the post's object (which is current post) on which  `mark_read_by_user` is being called.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh shouldn't this be `self.read_statuses.where(post_id: id, user_id: user.id).first_or_create`? From my understanding, your code will return the first ReadStatus of the post for any user (I may be wrong)

Comment: @MarkMerritt just checked the comments on the doc and I think you might be right about this. It's been a long time I used it.

Comment: @MarkMerritt how to find the weather the  current user is not viewed a particular post or not?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh how to find the weather the current user viewed a particular post or not?